# Is WUI a subset of GUI?

Tags: user-interface

Let's say I'm developing a web user interface for a program named `xxx`. As I have the prior knowledge of my potential users will not know what WUI and UI is, and they'll search for GUI instead. Thus I want to name my program as `xxxGUI` but it will be a web user interface. To make sure I don't make any mistake or misleading, is this a bad way to name my WUI or is web user interface already a subset of graphical user interfaces?

Comment: Depending on who you target audience is, they may not be familiar with GUI or UI either. I would not use anything like that in a URL: I would make the URL reveal what it does (Intention-revealing names in Agile-speak).

Comment: A WUI is not a subset of GUI (as it need not be graphical).

Comment: As this is not a very "hands-on" question, I think you'd have better luck on our sister site https://ux.stackexchange.com/. Make sure to read their help center and see what's on-topic there =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a Web user interface **is** a GUI, as well. Your suspicion is right, GUI is a very common term, while WUI is not and might be misleading. (Searching for GUI on Google returns 385MHits, while WUI just 8M, the first of which do not refer to UIs.) So just go ahead and call your WUI GUI.

Comment: There's a comment saying "WUI is not a subset of GUI (as it need not be graphical)." What are your opinions on this?

Comment: The relevant question is not if there exist WUIs that are not graphical, but if your particular WUI is graphical (which, you are correct, I silently assumed.)

Answer (score 0):

You may also your webapp xxxWebGUI, to make clear that it is not classic native desktop GUI app

Otherwise I am agree with the accepted answer web UI is almost always a GUI .

Unless you expect users access through textual browser akin to Mosaic/Linx or something too futuristic akin to virtual assistant/chatgpt

While it is not uncommon for developers and computer scientists alike contrast GUI vs web UI and assume GUI to be reserved to a desktop apps, more solid sources like Wikipedia or Britanica define GUI as

> a form of user interface that allows users to interact with electronic
> devices through graphical icons and audio indicator such as primary
> notation, instead of text-based UIs, typed command labels or text
> navigation.

which make web UI a subset of GUI.

Whole Computer Science and Software Engineering subject of

GUI testing of Web Apps

imply that it is fine to consider web UI as a GUI

REFERENCES

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface
2. Fulcini, Tommaso, and Luca Ardito. "Gamified Exploratory GUI Testing of Web Applications: a Preliminary Evaluation." 2022 IEEE International Conference on Software Testing, Verification and Validation Workshops (ICSTW). IEEE, 2022.
3. Sakal, Marton. "GUI vs. WUI through the Prism of Characteristics and Postures." Management Information Systems 5.1 (2010): 003-006.